# How can I insert picture in footer section with Javascript office.js

Tags: javascript, typescript, api, office-addins

I am using the version https://appsforoffice.microsoft.com/lib/1.1/hosted/office.js but reading the information there is not information about how insert in the footer and I don't find the property related with pictures

Any solution?

Comment: Can you share your code and what you´ve done so far ?

Comment: var footer = sheet.pageLayout.headersFooters.defaultForAllPages;
      footer.load({ $all: true });
      await context.sync();

    
      footer.set({ centerFooter: "&11 Page &P of &N"});
      footer.leftFooter
      footer.rightFooter = "&G";
      await context.sync();
    });

Comment: I dont find the option two insert a picture in the footer, do you know how can I insert a picture in the excel